# Running KVM on Linux Live Stick

Tags: debian, kvm, qemu, live-usb

I have built a Debian Live Stick using this [guide](http://willhaley.com/blog/create-a-custom-debian-live-environment/) and Jessie instead of Wheezy. 
The reason being I want to have a Live Stick with Cuckoo Sandbox and KVM/QEMU installed. I also had to switch syslinux with extlinux because FAT32 could not handle a filesystem with the VMs inside (>4gB size). 
I can boot it and everything seems in place, but a lot of daemons are not running.

Currently I am struggling to get libvirtd to run. 
I'm using xterm since gnome-terminal refuses to startup and I tried using `/etc/init.d/libvirtd start` and it fails:

```
libvirtd.serviceJob for libvirtd.service failed.
```

`systemctl status libvirtd.service` gives:

```
libvirtd.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Failed to start Virtualization daemon.
Unit libvirtd.service entered failed state.
```

with `journalctl -xn` giving basically the same information.

Has anybody clues on how to get those daemons to run (at best at startup)?

Thanks and best regards

### Edit 1

Ahhh, I found more information in the `/var/log/libvirt/libvirtd.log`

```
info : libvirt version: 1.2.9, package: 9+deb8u2 (buildd 2016-03-25-21:58.25 x86-csail-01)
error : virtFileGetHugepageSize:2934 : not a hugetlbfs mount: '/dev/hugepages'
error : virStateInitialize.749 : Initialization of QEMU state driver faild: internal error: not a hugetlbfs mount: '/dev/hugepages'
error : daemonRunStateInit:921 : Driver state initialization failed
```

Google tells me hugepages is for custom/bigger RAM pagesizes. But according to my `/etc/libvirt/libvirtd.conf` I have hugepages commented (which is the default)

### Edit 2

For my [libvirtd.conf](http://pastebin.com/GnUr9HxC). Note: I changed `log_level` back to `3`.

### Edit 3

I installed cuckoo and kvm using [this guide](https://infosecspeakeasy.org/t/howto-build-a-cuckoo-sandbox/27) although I altered a few steps (using stable instead of testing Debian), swapped some packages with others and left out packages not relevant for my use-case.
When just now trying to install QEMU/KVM while on the live linux yields the same errors as when trying to start it. 
So I ran `apt-get install qemu-kvm libvirt-clients libvirt-daemon virt-manager` and added the user to the according groups:

```
usermod -a -G kvm cuckoo
usermod -a -G libvirt cuckoo
```

### Edit 4

I altered the guide and I'll try to explain the important parts. 
I only have two users: `root` and `cuckoo`.
`sudo` is not installed and `cuckoo` is in the cuckoo and the kvm and libvirt groups. It is responsible for running cuckoo and kvm/qemu.

### Edit 5

While on the live system I removed kvm with

```
apt-get purge qemu-kvm libvirt-clients libvirt-daemon virt-manager
apt-get clean
apt-get autoremove
```

and reinstalled it with

```
apt-get install qemu-kvm libvirt-clients libvirt-daemon virt-manager
```

then I received then following error from apt

```
Job for libvirtd.service failed. See 'systemctl status libvirtd.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript libvirtd, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing package libvirt-daemon-system (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up libx86-1:i386 (1.1+ds1-10) ...
Setting up bridge-utils (1.5-9) ...
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
```

Maybe it has to do with the locales? I have a German keyboard layout installed and set `/etc/default/locale` to `LANG=de_DE.UTF-8`. Maybe this is wrong and also why `gnome-terminal` doesn't start?

---

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44109/discussion-on-question-by-milchdealer-running-kvm-on-linux-live-stick).

Comment: run `locale-gen "de_DE.UTF-8"` and `dpkg-reconfigure locales` and try again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much deliberation and messing around with configuration files and failed reinstall attempts, here is the solution if you are German:

```
locale-gen "de_DE.UTF-8"

dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

and reinstall the qemu-kvm components.

**Edit for people from the future**

This only works in this particular case as the initial "hugepage" errors were irrelevant. It turns out that they were just a by-product of errors that occurred during installation of the qemu-kvm components.

These errors themselves were due to the locale settings.

Comment: When doing the reconfiguation use "SPACE" to mark de_DE.UTF-8 and only then press "ENTER" so it really configure it.

Comment: What do locales have to do with hugepages? How does this solution work?

Comment: We established that the hugepage errors stopped a little while after beginning the troubleshooting process and OP tried to reinstall. The post install cleanup failed with an error about locales so I suggested this fix. This appears to have been the issue the whole time for this particular case.

Comment: Correct. Shall I remove the logs about hugepages? It might mislead people who are googling with similiar issues.

Comment: I edited my answer to clarify.